# Meaning and origin of "hustle, score, use"

Tags: meaning, etymology

In a movie about drug addiction they used this combination of words:

> hustle, score, use

They said it was always the same pattern - but what does it mean and where does it come from?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All three are slang for the life of an addict:

- hustle: do what you have to to get some money. It could involve honest work, stealing, begging, borrowing, whatever it takes
- score: find a drug dealer and buy some drugs
- use: take drugs

Comment: hm, I'm not so sure about "score", but I think you might be right. up-voting and hoping someone else will chip in.

Comment: Score is used correctly here.  See: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/score `The act or an instance of buying illicit drugs.`

Comment: @slim: yep, all ok, I remember it was in the latest season of Beavis and Butthead, so yeah, you got my up-vote. great job!

Answer (score 4):

**Q: ... and where does it come from?**

It's not a set phrase but three individual words, the first two of which are slang.

- **hustle**: "Sense of "to get in a quick, illegal manner" is 1840 in Amer.Eng.; that of "to sell goods aggressively" is 1887." ([Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hustle&allowed_in_frame=0))
- **score**: "to find and purchase drugs. [US, (1926): ERH: 1982, DWM: 1936, BVB: 1942, D&B: 1970c, ..." (*[The Slang and Jargon of Drugs and Drink](http://www.google.fi/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=inauthor%3a%22Richard%20A.%20Spears%22#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&tbm=bks&source=hp&q=inauthor%3a%22Richard%20A.%20Spears%22%20score&pbx=1&oq=inauthor%3a%22Richard%20A.%20Spears%22%20score&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=3466l4130l0l4392l6l5l0l0l0l0l186l491l2.3l5l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=ed9db0307fcc3b0c&biw=1920&bih=1062)*)
- **use**: "mid-13c., from O.Fr. *user* "use, employ, practice," from V.L. **usare* "use," frequentative form of pp. stem of L. *uti* "to use," in Old L. *oeti* "use, employ, exercise, perform," of unknown origin. Replaced O.E. *brucan* (see *brook* (v.))." ([Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=use&allowed_in_frame=0))

Answer (score 0):

Definitely correct use, think of it this way: if one is playing a game or sport the players must work hard and fast to get a point, a coach might say "come on lets hustle out there". The focus  is to score a goal.  After which the player or team celebrates for achieving their goal, use.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Nick! Yes, this expression may have a sporting origin. Can you improve your answer with any examples, say from a sports journal or movie script? Or other material that supports your answer?